# user.permissionsBoundary returns NULL while retrieving information from AWS using Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am using AWS Java SDK v2 to list users using the code defined [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/iam/src/main/java/com/example/iam/ListUsers.java) on the AWS GitHub repo.

```
 public static void listAllUsers(IamClient iam) {

    try {
        boolean done = false;
        String newMarker = null;

        while (!done) {
            ListUsersResponse response;

            ListUsersRequest request;
            if (newMarker == null) {
                request = ListUsersRequest.builder().build();
            } else {
                request = ListUsersRequest.builder()
                        .marker(newMarker).build();
            }

            response = iam.listUsers(request);

            for (User user : response.users()) {
                System.out.format("\n Retrieved user %s", user.userName());
                System.out.println("\nPermission Boundary: " + user.permissionsBoundary());
            }

            if (!response.isTruncated()) {
                done = true;
            } else {
                newMarker = response.marker();
            }
        }
    } catch (IamException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

It returns NULL for `user.permissionsBoundary()`.  Here is the output for print statements in the above code.

```
 Retrieved user jamshaid
Permission Boundary: null

 Retrieved user luminadmin
Permission Boundary: null

 Retrieved user test
Permission Boundary: null
```

When I run the following command in AWS CloudShell on AWS console, it returns the PermissionBoundary for the users it is defined.

```
aws iam get-user --user-name test
```

Here is the sample output from AWS CloudShell.
[image: console output]
I am using the same account to make both requests.

Comment: I tried out your code, I run into the same issue. I believe this is a bug in the SDK. [@smac2020](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435543/smac2020) could you confirm this?

Comment: I will look into this,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is an issue, but the programmed behavior. From the [API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html):

> IAM resource-listing operations return a subset of the available attributes
> for the resource. For example, this operation does not return tags, even
> though they are an attribute of the returned object. To view all of the
> information for a user, see [GetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html).

This is stated as well in the API [javadocs](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/iam/IamClient.html#listUsers-software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.ListUsersRequest-).

In the console you are using `get-user`, not [`list-users`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-users.html), and this is why the command is returning all the information about the user, `PermissionsBoundary` within it.

Please, try instead using:

```
aws iam list-users
```

and check the output, it should match the result you obtained with the Java SDK, it will not contain `PermissionsBoundary` either.

If you want to obtain the same results that you are currently getting with the command `aws iam get-user --user-name test` from Java code, you can use the [`getUser` method](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/iam/IamClient.html#getUser-software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.GetUserRequest-) in `IamClient`. Try Something like:

```java
GetUserRequest request = GetUserRequest.builder()
  .userName("test")
  .build()
;

GetUserResponse response = iam.getUser(request);
User user = response.user();
System.out.println("\nPermission Boundary: " + user.permissionsBoundary());
```

The [`User` class](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/iam/model/User.html) is reused in both operations, `get` and `list`, but only in the former all the fields are populated.

Comment: what should be the Java API way to get this? As I have checked the User Class and it contains  private final AttachedPermissionsBoundary permissionsBoundary;. which means that SDK is coded to return it but due to some reasons or bugs, it always returns null

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If you want to obtain the same results that you are currently getting with the command `aws iam get-user --user-name test` from Java code, you can use the [`getUser` method](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/iam/IamClient.html#getUser-software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.GetUserRequest-). The [`User` class](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/iam/model/User.html) is reused in both operations, `get` and `list`, but only in the former all the fields are populated. I updated the answer.

Comment: I provided a code sample as well. I hope it helps.

Comment: @JAMSHAID Were you able to test the proposed code? Did it work?

Comment: yeah. @jccampanero I got it implemented before you added the code following your previous suggestions. I will mark it as an answer. But, the SDK should work for all the scenario it contains rather than just returning null or it should return some error message.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @JAMSHAID. Well, I think that certainly the documentation could be improved to clarify the fields that are actually sent in the operation. But on the other hand think about it: the API is autogenerated for every supported SDK language, and it conforms to the REST API exposed by the service. In such scenario, it is usual to reuse certain classes, but only use them partially, as in this use case. The only way I can think could solve the problem is to use different classes for every operation, but it has drawbacks as well. I hope you will get some feedback...

Comment: ... in the issue you opened.

Answer (score 2):

I have confirmed this behavior by setting a permission boundary on an IAM user in the AWS Management Console. I changed the ListUsers example to include this code:

```
 for(User user : response.users()) {
    System.out.format("\n Retrieved user %s", user.userName());
    AttachedPermissionsBoundary permissionsBoundary = user.permissionsBoundary();
    if (permissionsBoundary != null)
        System.out.format("\n Permissions boundary details %s", permissionsBoundary.permissionsBoundaryTypeAsString());
   }
```

...

The **permissionsBoundary()** method does return null - even though the permission is set. This is a bug.

My advice here is to log a Github issue here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2

I also tested this with Kotlin SDK. Same result.

```
suspend fun listAllUsers() {

        IamClient { region = "AWS_GLOBAL" }.use { iamClient ->
            val response = iamClient.listUsers(ListUsersRequest { })
            response.users?.forEach { user ->
                println("Retrieved user ${user.userName}")
                val permissionsBoundary = user.permissionsBoundary
                if (permissionsBoundary != null)
                    println("Permissions boundary details ${permissionsBoundary.permissionsBoundaryType.toString()}")

            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for confirming the issue. I have opened a Bug report on GitHub. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/2944